# Task in synchronous application - IO bound

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, concurrency, io, task

We are working on a old comparator.

When an user make a research, we are calling 10-30 different webservice (REST, SOAP) at the same time. Pretty classic so. Each webservice is reprensented by a Client in our application.

So the code is like:

```
//Get the request list of client to call
clientRqListToCall = BuildRequest(userContext);
List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

//Call the different client
Foreach (ClientRequest clientRq in clientRqListToCall) {
    Task task = Task.Run(() => CallClient(clientRq));
    taskList.Add(task);
}
//wait client until timeOut
Task mainWaiterTask = Task.WhenAll(taskList);
mainTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
mainTask.Wait(timeout);
```

Simple. (Not sure the configureAwait is needed). The response of each client is store in a field of ClientRequest, so we don't use mainTask.Result (if a client Timeout, we need to be able to continue with another's ones, and they timeout a lot! Client call behaviours are pretty similar to a fireandforget).

The application is a little old, our search engine is synchronous.  The call of the different webservice are in the different CallClient callTree, according the to research context, 5 to 15 different function are call before the webservice call. Each webservice call is pretty long (1 to 15s each) ! This point seems to be important ! These are not pings simple pings requests.

Actions / Changes ?

So this is an I/O bound problem, we know Task.Run work pretty well for CPU-bound problem and not for I/O, the question is how to make this code better?

We read a lot of different article on the subject, thanks to Stephen Cleary (http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)
But we arenot sure of our choice / road map, that s why i post this ticket.

- We could make the code asynchronous, but we would have to rework the whole CallClient call tree (hundreds of functions). It is the only solution ? Of course we could migrate webservice  one by one using bool argument hack (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx).
  => **Must we start with the most costly (in term of IO) webservice, or only the number of webservice call is important, and so we should start the easiest?**
  In others words, if i got 1 bigs client, with a 10s response average and a lot of data, must we start to async then first? Or should be start with littles ones (1-2s) with the same amount of data. I could be wrong but a thread is lock in synchronous way until task.run() finish so obvisouly the 10s Task lock a thread for the whole time, but in term of I/O free a thread asap could be better. Does the amount of data download is important? or should we only thinck in term of webservice timer?
- Task.Run use the application threadPool, we have to choice between .Run(...) or Task.Factory.StartNew(..., TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning) in order to (lots of the time),
  create new thread and so maybe got a better.
  => i made some test on subjet, using a console application, .Run() seems to be 25% to 33% faster than Task.Factory.StartNew in all scenario. 
  Of course this is an expected result, but on a webapp with like 200 users,
  i am not sure the result would be the same, i fear the pool to be full and the Task jump to each others without be ended. 
  Note: If startNew is used, WaitAll(timeout) remplace WhenAll.

Today we got in average 20 to 50 customers can make a research at the same time. The application work without big issues, we dont have deadlock, but sometimes we can see some delay in the task execution in our side. Our Cpu usage is pretty low (<10%), Ram is green too (<25%)

I know there is plenty of tickets about Tasks, but it s hard to merge them together to match our problem. And we also read contradictory advices.

Answer (score -2):

I have used Parallel.ForEach to handle multiple I/O operations before, I did not see it mentioned above. I am not sure it will handle quite what you need seeing the function that is passed into the loop is that same for each. Maybe coupled with a strategy pattern / delegates you can achieve what you need.